# are static classes shared among different threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, static

I need to share a value between threads without exceeding it's boundary. Does a static variable do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "without exceeding its boundary?"

Answer (score 12):

You mean you want the variable to be thread-local?

You can either use the [`[ThreadStatic]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) attribute or the [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) class from .NET 4.

Personally I'd prefer `ThreadLocal<T>` if you *are* using .NET 4 - but better still would be to avoid this sort of context if you can. Can you encapsulate the information into an *instance* which is used to start the thread, for example?

Comment: @Gik25: I would still try to design your code so it *didn't* rely on this. It will be clearer and easier to test if you explicitly give each object its context.

Comment: I've got a multithreaded application where every thread is dedicated to the elaboration of a set of input data that now are accessible as follow: 
`FornituraHelper dati_fornitura = workflow.TemporaryData["Fornitura"] as FornituraHelper;`

My purpose is to easily access this data as follow:
`FornituraHelper dati_fornitura = TemporaryData.Fornitura;`

`TemporaryData.Fornitura` would be static, like Transaction.Current its shared all over the workflow. But since every thread executes a different WKF it must not overcome thread's limit (the ideal would be to be local to the WKF).

Comment: @Gik25: As I've said, you *could* use thread-locals for that, but I personally wouldn't. I would give each processing task the context explicitly.

Answer (score 12):

Static variables are shared across multiple threads within an AppDomain.  All threads will see, and act, upon the same instance of a static variable.  As such, if you're using static, you will likely want to use some form of synchronization to protect the access of that variable.

If you want to have a thread-local variable, the [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) class makes this easy.  It provides a means of generating and using data that is unique per thread.

Answer (score 3):

You decorate it with the `ThreadStaticAttribute`, to make the static variable share across only the thread it is initialized in.

Static variables by default are across all threads in an AppDomain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, apply the[ThreadStaticAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes  You need to watch out for synchronization though.